# Difference Between These REG Query Commands passed to For Loop in Batch, Trailing '\'s

Tags: cmd

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%n%\ /v InstallDir') do set dir=%%i

for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%n%(%id%)\ /v InstallDir') do set dir=%%i
```

For some reason the first for loop works, while the second one fails. Cmd says it did not expect the trailing '\' after (%id%)

So I have to write it like this

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%name%(%a%) /v InstallDir') do set dir=%%i
```

Does anyone know why the trailing '\' is acceptable in the first for loop but not the second?

Perfectly valid question asked by CausingUnderflowsEverywhere which may be useful to others with a similar problem, but unfortunately deleted prematurely with incorrect conclusion.

(as a matter of record)

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere : "Oh. In For loops, your command can't contain a Parenthesis or else it will close the for loop... I see." Er, no. The solution is very simple. You need to escape the offending `)` with a preceding caret `^` to tell batch that the closing parenthesis is part of the **data** not the **command**

Answer (score 0):

Escape the offending ) with a preceding caret ^ to tell batch that the closing parenthesis is part of the data not the command.

(As I say, it's just to correct a misconception)

Answer (score 0):

Escape *all* offending characters using double quotes as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('
  REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%n%(%id%)" /v InstallDir
    ') do set "dir=%%i"
```

should work even if `%n%` or `%id%` contains a white space character.

**Important**: no trailing `\` backslash in **double-quoted registry key name**.

Verified with another registry key(s) containing spaces, `()` parentheses, `|` vertical lines (pipes), `<>` redirectors…

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Connection Manager
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Transaction Server\Setup(OCM)
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Forms\B5 (ISO)
HKCR\Installer\Assemblies\C:|Program Files (x86)|Microsoft Help Viewer|v2.1|HlpViewer.exe
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\Intel(R) ME Application
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fax\Outbound Routing\Groups\<All devices>
```